# How can I add quotes to the beginning/end of every URL in a python list?

Tags: python

Simple inquiry here that I can't seem to figure out. I've written a line of code to add commas to the end of a list of several hundred URLs as so:

```
with open('bdall.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    new_line = ', '.join(lines)
```

But how do I modify this (or write new code) to also put all of the URLs from that text file into quotes so that I can paste them all into a program I am writing?

The output of the above is:

```
http://www.metrolyrics.com/til-i-fell-in-love-with-you-lyrics-bob-dylan.html,
http://www.metrolyrics.com/i-heard-that-lonesome-whistle-lyrics-bob-dylan.html,
etc.
```

But I need

```
"http://www.metrolyrics.com/til-i-fell-in-love-with-you-lyrics-bob-dylan.html", "http://www.metrolyrics.com/i-heard-that-lonesome-whistle-lyrics-bob-dylan.html",
etc.
```

Comment: This code does not "add commas to the end of a list".

Comment: You know how to add a comma to every line, but not how to put quotation marks around each line?

Comment: It adds commas to the end of each line. I  literally have the output so idk what you mean

Comment: I can add one to the end  with '", ' but how do I also add to the beginning

Comment: I'm still learning

Comment: What if you added `'","'` to the end?

Comment: `join` does not add to the *end* of each line; it inserts *between* each pair of adjacent lines.

Comment: Then i'd be a genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly passing "lines" as parameter for the ".join()" method, you can turn it into a **list comprehension** where you just need to format each line like this:

```
with open('bdall.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    new_line = ', '.join([f'"{line}"' for line in lines])
```

With this solution, the possibilities are endless.
I hope that was helpful